# NSDictionnary to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary that comes like that : (
1,
2,
3
)
And I would like to assign a NSString like this: 123, how? Thank you

My code :

```
NSDictionary *keys = [self.json valueForKeyPath:@"survey.questions.id"][0][0];

NSString *keysString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my dictionary is %@", keys];
```

Comment: It's seems that is is an array and not a dictionary, or am I missing something?

Comment: @lorenzoliveto It is a NSDictionnary that will look into NSArray

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want a string with the keys of the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSString *result = [[keys valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```